# A question on G-formula given by Targeted Learning: Causal Inference for Observational and Experimental Data

Tags: causality, causal-diagram

According to page 33 of *Targeted Learning: Causal Inference for Observational and Experimental Data* written by Mark J. van der Laan, when the distribution of exogenous variable $U$ is such that, for each $s$, $A_s$ is independent of $L_d$, given $Pa(A_s)$, then the g-formula is given as

$$P(L_d=l_d)=\prod_{r=1}^RP(L_r=l_r|Pa_d(L_r)=Pa_d(l_r)),$$

where $\{A_s:s\}$ are the intervention nodes, $Pa(A_s)$ are parents of $A_s$, $L_r$ is the endogenous node except for the intervention nodes, $L_d$ are intervened $\{L_r:r\}$, $Pa_d(L_r)$ are the parents of $L_r$ with the intervention nodes among these parent nodes deterministically set by intervention $d$.

In the graph drawed below,

[image]

I think the joint distribution of $(W,X,Y)$ at $A=1$ should be

$$P(Y_1=y,X=x,W=w)=P(Y=y|X=x,W=w,A=1)P(X=x|W=w)P(W=w),$$

but according to the equation given above, it should be

$$P(Y_1=y, X=x, W=w)=P(Y=y|X=X,W=w,A=1)P(X=x)P(W=w).$$

Do I misunderstand g-formula?

Comment: What you wrote is not the g-formula, it is only part of the g-formula for a single value of $w,x$. The g-formula for your DAG would be $P(Y^a) = \sum_{w,x} P(Y|A=a,W=w,X=x)P(W=w,X=x)$. I would recommend reading Snowden et al. (2011). *American Journal of Epidemiology*, 173(7), 731-738. as an introduction to the g-formula